# How to divide data into columns with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I display results from an object into columns like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Category name</a></li>
</ul>
```

Regardless of results returned to `@categories = Category.all` I want to divide them up into three columns like this. **What's the best way programmatically to do it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method can help you

```
%w(a s d f g h).each_slice(3) {|x| p x}
["a", "s", "d"]
["f", "g", "h"]
```

In HAML, you can handle it by this way

```
- cats = Array.new(3, [])
  = @categories.each_slice(3) do |category|
    - cats = cats.zip(category).map(&:flatten)
  - cats.each do |subcat|
    %ul
      - subcat.each do |l|
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"}
            = l
```

Comment: That's nice indeed! But what about when the number of elements returned is not 9 (and doesn't divide nicely in 3). How to have the first column take the extra 1?

Comment: you're going to have to have an another block iterating through the returned array and writing the ul/li elements, `x` in this case

Comment: @cmwright, thanks for comment, seems like my answer was incorrect, so I updated it

Comment: @user1049097, I hope now it fixed

Comment: As @Delba's answer says, in_groups (or in_groups_of) is probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

Rails has a dedicated way to do that using [in_groups](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html):

```
<% @categories.in_groups(3, false) do |group| %>
<ul>
  <% group.each do |category| %>
  <li><%= category.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

The second argument of in_groups (which is false in this case) means that this code won't produce empty list items if @categories.size isn't a multiple of 3.